# Link to a telegram bot with pre-written command

Tags: telegram, chatbot, telegram-bot

I'm writing a telegram bot now and I have a question. As I know any user can link to a bot using "@" symbol, like this @my_bot. Is there any possibility to make such a link, that when a user click on it, not only he is redirected to this bot, but also a specific command is sent to this bot by a user automatically.
Something like this @my_bot/my_command. I've tried this link, but it doesn't work. I don't know, if it is possible, maybe you do.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

You can use a deep link adding an additional parameter

```
https://t.me/mybot?start=task_name
```

The deep link opens the bot with the `start` command, the additional parameter is passed to your handler to customise what the start command_handler should do.

Comment: Ok^ thank you, and is it possible to make it running any other command?

Comment: It looks like the start command is the only option when deep linking https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking

Comment: @BeppeC according to the mentioned docs, there is also a "startgroup" parameter for deep linking.

Comment: Current docs URL is https://core.telegram.org/api/links#bot-links

Comment: Not working if telergam is running in background